# Product Options Design Pattern

Tags: design-patterns, architecture

I have a Product and product has number of configurable options of different types, some types are simple: string, number, boolean and so on, but some are quite complex and contain various information, for exmaple details about booking:booing id, dates and location.

Currently we serialize option value as json string and just dump them in NVARCHAR(MAX). It is quite simple, however it is hard to implement efficient search for these values.

Is there any popular/good pattern for that problem?

Thanks

Comment: There is no design pattern which matches the given intent.

Comment: Is it is eCommerce system?
How user interacting with the given data?
The best will be create scale-able DB.

Comment: By saying "it is hard to implement efficient search", what **exactly** do you mean?